# Converting sub-queries to joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Given the following schema...

[image: Schema]
how would I go about converting the following query to use joins (to work with MySQL)?

```
SELECT submissions.SubmissionID,
(SELECT data.DataContent FROM data WHERE data.DataFieldName =
    (SELECT forms.FormEmailFieldName FROM forms WHERE forms.FormID = submissions.SubmissionFormID)
AND data.DataSubmissionID = submissions.SubmissionID) AS EmailAddress,
(SELECT data.DataContent FROM data WHERE data.DataFieldName =
    (SELECT forms.FormNameFieldName FROM forms WHERE forms.FormID = submissions.SubmissionFormID)
AND data.DataSubmissionID = submissions.SubmissionID) AS UserName
FROM submissions
WHERE submissions.SubmissionFormID = 4
```

Below is some sample data and my desired result...

```
+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| forms  |                    |                   |
+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| FormID | FormEmailFieldName | FormNameFieldName |
| 4      | UserEmailAddress   | UserName          |
| 5      | email              | name              |
+--------+--------------------+-------------------+

+--------------+------------------+
| submissions  |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| SubmissionID | SubmissionFormID |
| 10           | 4                |
| 11           | 5                |
| 12           | 5                |
+--------------+------------------+

+--------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  data  |                  |                  |                  |
+--------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| DataID | DataSubmissionID | DataFieldName    | DataContent      |
| 1      | 10               | UserEmailAddress | user@example.com |
| 2      | 10               | UserName         | Paul D'Otherone  |
| 3      | 11               | email            | bob@bobs.com     |
| 4      | 11               | name             | Bob Bobbington   |
| 5      | 11               | phone            | 01234 5678910    |
| 6      | 11               | country          | UK               |
| 7      | 12               | name             | Sheila Sausages  |
| 8      | 12               | country          | UK               |
+--------+------------------+------------------+------------------+

+--------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|      DESIRED RESULT      |                  |                 |
+--------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| submissions.SubmissionID | EmailAddress     | UserName        |
| 10                       | user@example.com | Paul D'Otherone |
| 11                       | bob@bobs.com     | Bob Bobbington  |
| 12                       | NULL             | Sheila Sausages |
+--------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Also see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78dea/1/0

I've tried various combinations of inner joins and left joins but can't get a result set in the same format as the above query. I am still learning how to use joins and am finding this hard to get my head around.

Comment: what do you try to accomplish with your query? Probably have some sample data and expected resultset?

Comment: Give us you query closest to the wanted result, and describe whats wrong with it. Also some sample data and wanted output would be nice.

Comment: I've added some sample data and my desired result set

Comment: @Olli there is a mistake in one of your inserts. `insert into submissions values (10,1),(11,5),(12,5);` should be `insert into submissions values (10,4),(11,5),(12,5);`

Comment: @Michael Aaaah.. shame on me... corrected it...  you can see the result then... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f917/1

Comment: @Olli thanks :) your query seems to return a row for each row in the data table but what I am after is a row for each row in the submissions table (i.e. each SubmissionID should only appear once in the result set). You can see this by removing the where clause.

Comment: @Olli to explain my requirement a bit more clearly... I want a row for each submission and an email address if available otherwise NULL and a name if available otherwise NULL

Comment: I also just realised my original query was incorrect and I have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Olli's and Gordon's suggestions I have come up with the following which gives the same result set as my original query...

```
SELECT 
  s.SubmissionID,
  d1.DataContent AS EmailAddress,
  d2.DataContent AS Username
FROM submissions s
INNER JOIN forms AS f1 ON (f1.FormID = s.SubmissionFormID)
LEFT JOIN data AS d1 ON (d1.DataFieldName = f1.FormEmailFieldName and d1.DataSubmissionID = s.SubmissionID)
LEFT JOIN data AS d2 ON (d2.DataFieldName = f1.FormNameFieldName and d2.DataSubmissionID = s.SubmissionID)
WHERE s.SubmissionFormID = 4
```

Does this seem like the correct way to go about achieving what I want?

Comment: Yup... looks fine for me. since you also want your NULL values, the LEFT JOIN is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Without having sample data, just a quick try:

```
SELECT 
  s.SubmissionID,
  d1.DataContent AS EmailAddress,
  d2.DataContent AS Username
FROM submissions s
JOIN forms AS f1 ON (f1.FormID = s.SubmissionFormID)
JOIN data AS d1 ON (d1.DataFieldName = f1.FormEmailFieldName)
JOIN data AS d2 ON (d2.DataFieldName = f1.FormNameFieldName)
WHERE s.SubmissionFormID = 4
```

sql fiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f917/1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one join to `forms` and two to `data`, one for each field.

```
SELECT s.SubmissionID, de.DataContent as EmailAddress,
       dn.DataContent as UserName
FROM submissions s LEFT JOIN
     forms f
     ON f.FormId = s.SubmissionFormID LEFT JOIN
     data dn
     ON d.DataFieldName = f.FormNameFieldName LEFT JOIN
     data de
     ON d.DataFieldName = f.FormEmailFieldName
WHERE s.SubmissionFormID = 4
```

In case there is missing data, then you want to use `LEFT JOIN`.  This will ensure that you get all the rows (which your original query does).

I also added table aliases into the query.  These make queries easier to write and to read.

Comment: A submission will always be related to a form. Therefore can the first left join be changed to an inner join?

Comment: @Michael . . . Yes.  Your original query would return `NULL` if this wasn't true.